# RabbitMQ + STOMP - can I create durable queue on subscribe?

Tags: queue, rabbitmq, stomp

Can I make RabbitMQ 3.4.1 create new DURABLE queue named "q123" when a STOMP client sends

```
SUBSCRIBE
destination: /amq/queue/q123
...
```

and use this queue for later subscriptions ?

Answer (score 3):

You can't create new queue outside STOMP gateway. You can `SEND` and `SUBSCRIBE` them, but not create new one.

STOMP may create it for you if you will refer to `/queue/<your-queue-name>` in vhost specified by your STOMP plugin settings (by default it is standard `/` vhost).

So such STOMP frame will create `new-random-one` durable queue in `/` vhost.

```
SUBSCRIBE
destination: /queue/new-random-one
```

Here is how to run it over raw shell (^@ stands for Ctrl+@, empty line before it matters):

```
nc localhost 61613
CONNECT

^@
CONNECTED
session:session-3IE6yYjn6borQ_4KLfxLMw
heart-beat:0,0
server:RabbitMQ/3.4.1
version:1.0

SUBSCRIBE
destination: /queue/new-random-one

^@
DISCONNECT

^@
```

So after that, even after disconnected, you'll see that `new-random-one` queue will still reside in default vhost.

For more, read details on [Destinations](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html#d) section of [RabbitMQ STOMP Adapter](https://www.rabbitmq.com/stomp.html) manual page.